# Publishing a c# console application from VS 2012 Express for Web.

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, console, publish

As a company we have recently upgraded all our development machines from Win7 VS 2010 to Win 8 with VS 2012. I've now hit a wall when trying to publish one of our existing c# console applications. When trying to publish it just errors saying

> the publish components are not available. You need to reinstall Visual
>   Studio to publish your application.

Reinstalls and Repairs do no fix this issue and it is the same on multiple machines. Has anyone else had this problem or found a solution to it? Really don't want to have to put VS2010 on our machines as well purely to publish one app.

Thanks.

Comment: Was this console app published and installed or did you just run it from the .exe in the debug folder?

Comment: Just trying to publish it from the source code. It works fine from the debug folder when testing but now need to package it up for deployment.

Comment: You can deploy your console app by going to the debug folder and copying the exe and the dlls. If you dont use any third party dlls, you can copy the exe just like that.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to recover the "publish" feature this way:

Using Visual Studio, unload the project and edit the project file.
Search for "OfficeVersion".
Change OfficeVersion from "16.0" to "15.0".
Save and reload the project file.

I found the answer at: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2132333/publish-components-are-not-available

Comment: This solved it for me as well in 2013.  I didn't try it initially because it just didn't seem like it would do anything but it worked.  Now I have to set it to 16 to debug and 15 to publish.

Comment: This also solved it for me when VS2012 Update 5 suddenly gave me this error, it didn't on friday... Changed from 16 to 15 only for OfficeVersion attribute. I can still debug with the version set to 15 on Office 2016 (365)

Answer (score 1):

Did you install service pack 4 for VS2012 ? If not, try install it. May be it can help [service pack 4 for VS2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305)

Comment: this may be, i read about that and users with the same problem resolved the issue with the above fix. +1

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but this happened to me today after a failed update to Windows 10 (not sure if that's the cause or bad timing).

It was caused by a corrupt machine.config file :

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config

I replaced it by the contents of machine.config.default to fix the issue.